# Add Column to a grid (observer) - Column ‘store_id’ in where clause is ambiguous issue

Tags: database, magento-1, collection, filter, order-grid

I'm adding a column to the order grid using observer approach:

1. On the event -> `sales_order_grid_collection_load_before` I'm adding a join to the collection
2. On the event -> `core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before` I'm adding a column to the grid

**EDIT** More Info:

On Event (1):

```
   public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
    $collection->addFilterToMap('store_id', 'main_table.store_id');
    $select = $collection->getSelect();
    $select->joinLeft(array('oe' => $collection->getTable('sales/order')), 'oe.entity_id=main_table.entity_id', array('oe.customer_group_id'));

}
```

On Event (2):

```
public function appendCustomColumn(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getBlock();
    if (!isset($block)) {
        return $this;
    }

    if ($block->getType() == 'adminhtml/sales_order_grid') {
        /* @var $block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid */
        $this->_addColumnToGrid($block);
    }
}

protected function _addColumnToGrid($grid)
{

    $groups = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id', array('gt' => 0))
        ->load()
        ->toOptionHash();
    $groups[0] = 'Guest';


    /* @var $block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid */
    $grid->addColumnAfter('customer_group_id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer Group'),
        'index' => 'customer_group_id',
        'filter_index' => 'oe.customer_group_id',
        'type' => 'options',
        'options' => $groups,
    ), 'shipping_name');
}
```

Everything work fine until I filter the grid with store view filter:
**Column ‘store_id’ in where clause is ambiguous issue**

I have printed the query:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `oe`.`customer_group_id` 
FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `oe` ON oe.entity_id=main_table.entity_id 
WHERE (store_id = '5') AND (oe.customer_group_id = '6')
```

As you case see `store_id` miss `main_table` alias.

To accomplish this I just need to set the `filter_index` for store Id column but **through the observer**
So the question is how can I do it **on the fly** ?
**Without overriding the block** class ? ( otherwise the observer approach is useless )

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Let's try this again with on other solution I mentioned before to you :-) , I have build the complete extension to show you how to add the field to the grid table. After that you only need a layout update file to add the column to you order grid page.

I called the extension Example_SalesGrid, but you can change it to your own needs.

Let's start by creating the module init xml in **/app/etc/modules/Example_SalesGrid.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Module bootstrap file
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Example_SalesGrid>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Sales />
            </depends>
        </Example_SalesGrid>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Next we create our module config xml in **/app/code/community/Example/SalesGrid/etc/config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Example_SalesGrid>
            <version>0.1.0</version> <!-- define version for sql upgrade -->
        </Example_SalesGrid>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <example_salesgrid>
                <class>Example_SalesGrid_Model</class>
            </example_salesgrid>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <example_salesgrid>
                <class>Example_SalesGrid_Block</class>
            </example_salesgrid>
        </blocks>
        <events>
            <!-- Add observer configuration -->
            <sales_order_resource_init_virtual_grid_columns>
                <observers>
                    <example_salesgrid>
                        <model>example_salesgrid/observer</model>
                        <method>addColumnToResource</method>
                    </example_salesgrid>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_resource_init_virtual_grid_columns>
        </events>
        <resources>
            <!-- initialize sql upgrade setup -->
            <example_salesgrid_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Example_SalesGrid</module>
                    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </example_salesgrid_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <!-- layout upgrade configuration -->
            <updates>
                <example_salesgrid>
                    <file>example/salesgrid.xml</file>
                </example_salesgrid>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Now we create the sql upgrade script in **/app/code/community/Example/SalesGrid/sql/example_salesgrid_setup/install-0.1.0.php**:

```
<?php
/**
 * Setup scripts, add new column and fulfills
 * its values to existing rows
 *
 */
$this->startSetup();
// Add column to grid table

$this->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $this->getTable('sales/order_grid'),
    'customer_group_id',
    'smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL'
);

// Add key to table for this field,
// it will improve the speed of searching & sorting by the field
$this->getConnection()->addKey(
    $this->getTable('sales/order_grid'),
    'customer_group_id',
    'customer_group_id'
);

// Now you need to fullfill existing rows with data from address table

$select = $this->getConnection()->select();
$select->join(
    array('order'=>$this->getTable('sales/order')),
    $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(
        'order.entity_id = order_grid.entity_id'
    ),
    array('customer_group_id' => 'customer_group_id')
);
$this->getConnection()->query(
    $select->crossUpdateFromSelect(
        array('order_grid' => $this->getTable('sales/order_grid'))
    )
);

$this->endSetup();
```

Next we create the layout update file in **/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/example/salesgrid.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <!-- main layout definition that adds the column -->
    <add_order_grid_column_handle>
        <reference name="sales_order.grid">
            <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>customer_group_id</columnId>
                <arguments module="sales" translate="header">
                    <header>Customer Group</header>
                    <index>customer_group_id</index>
                    <type>options</type>
                    <filter>Example_SalesGrid_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Customer_Group</filter>
                    <renderer>Example_SalesGrid_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Customer_Group</renderer>
                    <width>200</width>
                </arguments>
                <after>grand_total</after>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </add_order_grid_column_handle>
    <!-- order grid action -->
    <adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
        <!-- apply the layout handle defined above -->
        <update handle="add_order_grid_column_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
    <!-- order grid view action -->
    <adminhtml_sales_order_index>
        <!-- apply the layout handle defined above -->
        <update handle="add_order_grid_column_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_index>
</layout>
```

Now we need two Block files, one to create the filter options, **/app/code/community/Example/SalesGrid/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Customer/Group.php:**

```
<?php

class Example_SalesGrid_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Customer_Group extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Select  {

    protected $_options = false;

    protected function _getOptions(){

        if(!$this->_options) {
            $methods = array();
            $methods[] = array(
                'value' =>  '',
                'label' =>  ''
            );
            $methods[] = array(
                'value' =>  '0',
                'label' =>  'Guest'
            );

            $groups = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')
                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id', array('gt' => 0))
                ->load()
                ->toOptionArray();

            $this->_options = array_merge($methods,$groups);
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

And the second to translate the row values to the correct text that will be displayed, **/app/code/community/Example/SalesGrid/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/Customer/Group.php**:

```
<?php

class Example_SalesGrid_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Customer_Group extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract   {

    protected $_options = false;

    protected function _getOptions(){

        if(!$this->_options) {
            $methods = array();
            $methods[0] = 'Guest';

            $groups = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')
                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id', array('gt' => 0))
                ->load()
                ->toOptionHash();
            $this->_options = array_merge($methods,$groups);
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }

    public function render(Varien_Object $row){
        $value = $this->_getValue($row);
        $options = $this->_getOptions();
        return isset($options[$value]) ? $options[$value] : $value;
    }
}
```

The last file needed is only needed if you create an extra column from a table other than sales/order (sales_flat_order). All fields in sales/order_grid matching the column name from sales/order is automatically updated in the sales/order_grid table. If you need to add the payment option for example you will need this observer to add the field to the query so the data can be copied to the correct table. The observer used for this is in **/app/code/community/Example/SalesGrid/Model/Observer.php**:

```
<?php
/**
 * Event observer model
 *
 *
 */
class Example_SalesGrid_Model_Observer {

    public function addColumnToResource(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        // Only needed if you use a table other than sales/order (sales_flat_order)

        //$resource = $observer->getEvent()->getResource();
        //$resource->addVirtualGridColumn(
        //  'payment_method',
        //  'sales/order_payment',
        //  array('entity_id' => 'parent_id'),
        //  'method'
        //);
    }
}
```

This code is based on the example from <strike>http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/07/27/adding-order-attribute-to-orders-grid-in-magento-1-4-1.html</strike>

Hope the example above solves your problem.

Comment: Sorry I was not able to test it as I was traveling ... It sounds a bit more complicated that my approach ( does it work also for new order ? )

Comment: The grid observer handles the data changes at every change, because this is native Magento usage you do not need to create any joins to other tables, this speeds-up the query on large amounts of orders (all data is stored in sales_flat_order_grid).

Comment: When I try and use this I get the error **Warning: Missing argument 2 for Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::quoteInto()**

Answer (score 4):

Try to use these:

```
public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
{
    /**
     * @var $select Varien_DB_Select
     */
    $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
    $collection->addFilterToMap('store_id', 'main_table.store_id');
    $select     = $collection->getSelect();
    $select->joinLeft(array('oe' => $collection->getTable('sales/order')), 'oe.entity_id=main_table.entity_id', array('oe.customer_group_id'));
    if ($where = $select->getPart('where')) {
        foreach ($where as $key=> $condition) {
            if (strpos($condition, 'store_id')) {
                $value       = explode('=', trim($condition, ')'));
                $value       = trim($value[1], "' ");
                $where[$key] = "(main_table.store_id = '$value')";
            }
        }
        $select->setPart('where', $where);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should have been really accepted as the answer for the OP's observer approach.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need in your method `salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore` the following code `$collection->addFilterToMap('store_id', 'main_table.store_id');`? If not remove it and try the following:

```
protected function _addColumnToGrid($grid)
{
....... // here you code from your post above

    $storeIdColumn = $grid->getColumn('store_id');

    if($storeIdColumn) {
        $storeIdColumn->addData(array('filter_index' => 'main_table.store_id'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Already tried both :( `Column('store_id');` is not available on `core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before ` ( _prepareColumn() is called after so the column doesn't exist at that time )

`addFilterToMap` is not doing is job

Comment: any idea why addFilterToMap is not working ?

Comment: Soory I didn't have too much time to take a look this last days. Maybe tomorrow. Just an idea, because I remember a little bit of the reason why I told not using addFilterToMap, is how you use maybe incorrect, parameters are wrong or not used in good moment. It's just ideas from remembers.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the static column name you can use below method for all column. I can understand if use mageUz's answer that will work for one column and if you go for some other column then you might be getting same error. So below code gives you solution for all column simultaneously.

```
public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
    $select = $collection->getSelect();
    $select->joinLeft(array('order' => $collection->getTable('sales/order')), 'order.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',array('shipping_arrival_date' => 'shipping_arrival_date'));

    if ($where = $select->getPart('where')) {
        foreach ($where as $key=> $condition) {
            $parsedString = $this->get_string_between($condition, '`', '`');
    $yes = $this->checkFiledExistInTable('order_grid',$parsedString);
    if($yes){
        $condition = str_replace('`','',$condition);
        $where[$key] = str_replace($parsedString,"main_table.".$parsedString,$condition);
    }
        }
        $select->setPart('where', $where);
    }
}

 public function checkFiledExistInTable($entity=null,$parsedString=null){
   $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
   $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

    if($entity == 'order'){
       $table = 'sales/order';
    }elseif($entity == 'order_grid'){
        $table = 'sales/order_grid';
    }else{
        return false;
    }

     $tableName = $resource->getTableName($table);
    $saleField = $readConnection->describeTable($tableName);

    if (array_key_exists($parsedString,$saleField)){
       return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
 }

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
```