# Extending A Single Method Using Depends

Tags: module, grid, grid-serlization

I am trying to extend the admin order grid by adding a single column. I don't want to add all the logic again in my code, so the only method I'm calling is `_prepareColumns()`:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('customer_group', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Group'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'index' => 'increment_id',
    ));
    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

I've read [this article](http://magedev.com/2009/06/03/magento-overriding-model-block-or-helper/) on overriding methods, but I don't know if I'm following it correctly. My module file at `~/app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml` includes the following:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Adminhtml />
                <Mage_Core />
                <Mage_Sales />
            </depends>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

My `config.xml` file contains:

```
<config>
    ...
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_grid>Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    ...
</config>
```

On my testing site, I get only this `Customer Group` column on the grid. I am expecting all the columns AND this column. Am I wrong to think it will work like this?

My code is all in a custom module. Thanks.

A picture might help. I'm trying to edit this:

[image: Mage Adminhtml Sales Order Grid]

Comment: The depends from /app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml does not influence class inheritance.

In your new module, what class does your new grid block extends? Is the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid? Do you have rewrite rules in your module's config.xml file?

Comment: The class is `Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid` and it  extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`. Yes, please see the edit for `config.xml` code. Thx.

Comment: It should extend the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid, not the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PandaWebStudio for pointing out my error. Yes, I am an idiot.

I was extending the original class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`, which will add the single column. To get what I wanted, I needed to extend the class from Magento's sales order grid (which itself extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`):

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
```

All works perfectly now. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, and another thing I've noticed is that the new column index is increment_id, which I think is not what you want. The index should be the column name in the sql query. I think you also have to override the _prepareCollection() to get the customer group info from db.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution to add a column to the order grid, see my complete answer/solution in: [Add Column to a grid (observer) - Column ‘store_id’ in where clause is ambiguous issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4191/add-column-to-a-grid-observer-column-store-id-in-where-clause-is-ambiguous/4626#4626)

Comment: It's bit complicated solution, instead we can achieve it simply by rewriting single file.

Answer (score 0):

To add customer group column in Sales Order grid.
You can do it by rewriting **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid** class

```
 <?php
  class [CompanyName]_[ModuleName]_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
  {
    protected function _preparePage()
    {

        $this->getCollection()
             ->getSelect()
             ->join( array('customer'=> 'customer_entity'), 'customer.entity_id = main_table.customer_id', array('customer.group_id'));
        return parent::_preparePage();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {


        $groups = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id', array('gt'=> 0))
            ->load()
            ->toOptionHash();
        $this->addColumn('customer_group',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Group'),
                'width' => '70px',
                'index' => 'group_id',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'options' => $groups,
            ));

        $this->addColumnsOrder('customer_group', 'shipping_name');
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
  }
?>
```

I hope above code will be useful.