# Modify the Order Grid with Customer Information

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, grid, grid-serlization

I am trying to modify the order grid in which I require the customer information like active or deactivate which is my custom customer attribute so how can I display it in grid. I have also required to display it in order view template which I have already overridden it displayed it in that file.

> Note: I have modified the grid but not understanding how to display
>   the customer `custom information. I have added the field in the grid
>   remain is to populate it with customer data.

Comment: you mean to say you have one customer field/attribute called customer_activated(or Any other with "Activate/Deactivate" option values) that field/attribute you need to display in sales order grid?

Comment: Yes bijal do you have any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@GarthHuff

Try below class if we have customer attribute like "customer_activated"

```
<?php
  class [MyCompanyName]_[MyModuleName]_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
  {
    protected function _preparePage()
    {

         $collection  =  $this->getCollection(); 
         $customerActivated = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')->getResource()->getAttribute('customer_activated'); 
         $collection->getSelect()
                ->joinLeft(
                    array('customerActivatedTb' => $customerActivated->getBackend()->getTable()),
                    'main_table.customer_id = customerActivatedTb.entity_id AND customerActivatedTb.attribute_id = '.$customerActivated->getId(). ' AND customerActivatedTb.entity_type_id = '.Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')->getResource()->getTypeId(),
                    array('customer_activated' =>'customerActivatedTb.value') 
                );    
        return parent::_preparePage();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    { 
        $options =array(
                        0 => Mage::helper('core')->__('No'),
                        1 => Mage::helper('core')->__('Yes')
                    );
        $this->addColumn('customer_activated',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Activated'),
                'width' => '70px',
                'index' => 'customer_activated',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'options' => $options,
                 'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, 'customerActivatedFilter'),
            ));

        $this->addColumnsOrder('customer_activated', 'shipping_name');
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function customerActivatedFilter($collection, $column){
        $filterValue = $column->getFilter()->getValue();
        if(!is_null($filterValue)){
            $filterValue = trim($filterValue);
            $filterValue = preg_replace('/[\s]+/', ' ', $filterValue);

            $where   = $collection->getConnection()->quoteInto("customerActivatedTb.value = ?", $filterValue); 
            $collection->getSelect()->where($where);
        }
    }

  }
?>
```

I hope above code helps you!

Comment: Code Works fine....  i have to modified something according to my change . Btw it works great

Answer (score 0):

@GarthHuff you can see here [Extending A Single Method Using Depends](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5437/extending-a-single-method-using-depends/11306#11306) It's an example to add customer group column in sales order grid.
I haven't tested it for customer activated field.

Comment: What if i am having my attribute in the customer_eav_attribute

Comment: please checkout my above answer, it works for me :)