# Creating an extra field in sales order grid

Tags: adminhtml, order-grid

I need to insert the company name into the order grid. I added this to `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php` in the `function _prepareColumns()`

```
    $this->addColumn('billing_company', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Company Name'),
        'index' => 'billing_company',
    ));
```

It is not working. Is `billing_company` the wrong name or do I need to change something else were as well?

**UPDATE:** I think i need to add the propety to the `collection` variable and then it will work something like this  (i cant find the right one for company yet)

```
$collection->getSelect()->join($prefix.'sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = '.$prefix.'sales_flat_order.entity_id',array('shipping_method','customer_email','coupon_code','weight','base_tax_amount','tax_amount','base_discount_amount','discount_amount','base_total_refunded','total_refunded','customer_group_id'));
```

Comment: The billing_company is per default not present in the sales_flat_order_grid column. You will need to add the column to the grid and update the data, as mentioned here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5521/add-new-column-to-sales-flat-order-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i got it

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoab'=>$prefix.'sales_flat_order_address'),
    'main_table.entity_id = sfoab.parent_id AND sfoab.address_type="billing"',array('sfoab.street',
    'sfoab.city','sfoab.region','sfoab.postcode','sfoab.telephone','sfoab.company','sfoab.country_id'));
```

and in function `_prepareColumns()`

```
                $this->addColumn('company', array(
                    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill Company'),
                    'index' => 'company',
                    'filter_index' => 'sfoab.company',  
                ));
```