# add complete address in default columns in order grid

Tags: orders, grid, order-grid, column

I want to add complete address in default "Bill to Name" and "Ship to Name" columns in order grid in Magento admin.
I am attaching screen-shot for more explanation.
[image]
Please suggest me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to extend the order grid (assuming that it is already familiar to you).

in the extended php file app/code/local/Yournamespace/Yourmodule/Block/Adminhtml/.../Grid.php

```
class Yournamespace_Yourmodule_Block_..._Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid{
    protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass())
                    ->join(array('soa' => 'sales/order_address'), 'soa.parent_id=main_table.entity_id and soa.address_type = "billing"', array('full_address'=>'CONCAT(soa.firstname, " " , soa.lastname, ",<br/>", soa.street, ",<br/>", soa.city, ",<br/>", soa.region, ",<br/>", soa.postcode)' ), null,'left')
                    ->join(array('soas' => 'sales/order_address'), 'soas.parent_id=main_table.entity_id and soas.address_type = "shipping"', array('full_address_ship'=>'CONCAT(soas.firstname, " " , soas.lastname, ",<br/>", soas.street, ",<br/>", soas.city, ",<br/>", soas.region, ",<br/>", soas.postcode)' ), null,'left');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

...
```

then inside `protected function _prepareColumns()` method replace the following code

```
    $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
        'index' => 'billing_name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
        'index' => 'shipping_name',
    ));
```

with

```
    $this->addColumn('full_address', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Billing Address'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'index' => 'full_address',
    ));
    $this->addColumn('full_address_ship', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Address'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'index' => 'full_address_ship',
    ));
```

You're done!

> The other easy and recommended way would be using event and observer:

in your module config.xml

under config tag...

```
<config>
    ...
    <adminhtml>
    ...
        <events>
            <sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <vendor>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                          <class>yourmodule/adminhtml_observer</class>
                        <method>filterOrderCollection</method>
                    </vendor>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
            <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
                <observers>
                    <vendor>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>yourmodule/adminhtml_observer</class>
                        <method>saleOrderLayout</method>
                    </vendor>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
```

**in app/code/local/Yournamespace/Yourmodule/Model/Adminhtml/Observer.php**

```
<?php
    class Yournamespace_Yourmodule_Model_Adminhtml_Observer{

        public function filterOrderCollection($observer){
            $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderGridCollection();
            $collection->join(array('soa' => 'sales/order_address'), 'soa.parent_id=main_table.entity_id and soa.address_type = "billing"', array('full_address'=>'CONCAT(soa.firstname, " " , soa.lastname, ",<br/>", soa.street, ",<br/>", soa.city, ",<br/>", soa.region, ",<br/>", soa.postcode)' ), null,'left');
            $collection->join(array('soas' => 'sales/order_address'), 'soas.parent_id=main_table.entity_id and soas.address_type = "shipping"', array('full_address_ship'=>'CONCAT(soas.firstname, " " , soas.lastname, ",<br/>", soas.street, ",<br/>", soas.city, ",<br/>", soas.region, ",<br/>", soas.postcode)' ), null,'left');
        }

        public function saleOrderLayout($evt){
            $tabBlock = $evt->getBlock();
            if($tabBlock instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid){
                $tabBlock->addColumnAfter('full_address', array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Billing Address'),
                'width' => '80px',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'index' => 'full_address',
                ), 'created_at');
                $tabBlock->addColumnAfter('full_address_ship', array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Address'),
                'width' => '80px',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'index' => 'full_address_ship',
                ), 'full_address');
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: using <br/> tag (in join method) is not recommended. You can use "\n" character instead. As i had some problem with my compiler i used <br/> tag

Comment: great! it's works. you are rock (I replaced <br> with \n) but how can I remove or replace default columns "bill to name" and "ship to name"?

Comment: that depends on which method you used. If you used the first method, you can just comment out those two columns. If second method: in the observer use `billing_name` instead of `full_address` and `shipping_name` instead of `full_address_ship`.

Comment: Sorry but it's not replaced. I am using second method. I tried this code: 

`$tabBlock->addColumnAfter('billing_name', array(
         'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Billing Address'),
          'width' => '80px',
          'type'  => 'text',
           'index' => 'full_address',
           ), 'created_at'); `

Comment: did u replace all the instance of `full_address` and `full_address_ship`? can you post the screenshot of your grid?

Comment: oh, I didn't replace  `full_address` and `full_address_ship` with `billing_name` and `shipping_name` in `filterOrderCollection`. Now it's works! Great work @Shathish, thanks :)

Comment: glad to see that :)

Comment: I tried first approach but unfortunately sorting does not work using this approach "Its saying unknown column". any help ?

Comment: how to display country name only ?

Comment: @Shathish : How can i add custom attribute in sales order grid, https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/196004/57334

Comment: @Shathish Thank you for this. But How to use filter_index to search for full_address ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to change the columns shown in the order grid is to use the observer that updates the sales_flat_order_grid table. In an earlier question I did a complete setup on how to extend the grid, see: [Add Column to a grid (observer) - Column ‘store_id’ in where clause is ambiguous issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4191/add-column-to-a-grid-observer-column-store-id-in-where-clause-is-ambiguous/4626#4626)

In this example you have to change the customer_group_id with the addresses used. In the observer you will then have to add the collection of the data so that it gets saved to the grid table every time.

Alternatively you can use the renderer for the column to format and display the data for the address, but this requires that you do a lot of extra queries when loading the grid.

Comment: Absolutely! I initially started to type my answer using observer, but changed my mind. I'll update my answer with that though :)

Comment: How can i add custom attribute in sales order grid, https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/196004/57334

Answer (score 0):

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',array('telephone','city','postcode' ) )->where("sales_flat_order_address.address_type = 'billing'");

           $this->addColumn('telephone', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Mobile'),
            'index' => 'telephone',
            'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order_address.telephone',
            ));

            $this->addColumn('city', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('City'),
            'index' => 'city',
            'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order_address.city',
            ));

            $this->addColumn('postcode', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Pincode'),
            'index' => 'postcode',
            'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order_address.postcode',
            ));
```

Comment: Modifying core Magento files is strongly in conflict with best practices.