# How to Display complete billing and shipping address in admin order grid of magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-address

I want to display in order admin grid "bill to name"  column have complete billing address and "ship to name" column have complete shipping address in magento 1.9. i already followed following links but not working.

[how to add customer's shipping address detail in Admin > Sales > Order grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45572/how-to-add-customers-shipping-address-detail-in-admin-sales-order-grid)

[add complete address in default columns in order grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12739/add-complete-address-in-default-columns-in-order-grid)

Anybody knows answer please share.

Your help will be appreciated.

**This is my controller**

```
<?php
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}
protected function _getCollectionClass()
{
    return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{

    $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'index' => 'increment_id',
    ));

    if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
            'index'     => 'store_id',
            'type'      => 'store',
            'store_view'=> true,
            'display_deleted' => true,
        ));
    }

    $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
        'index' => 'created_at',
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'width' => '100px',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
        'index' => 'billing_name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
        'index' => 'shipping_name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
        'index' => 'base_grand_total',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
        'index' => 'grand_total',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('status', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
        'index' => 'status',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'width' => '70px',
        'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
    ));

    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '50px',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'     => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                        'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                        'field'   => 'order_id',
                        'data-column' => 'action',
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
        ));
    }
    $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);

    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
        ));
    }

    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Hold'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
        ));
    }

    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Unhold'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
        ));
    }

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
    ));

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
    ));

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
    ));

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
    ));

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('print_shipping_label', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Shipping Labels'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel'),
    ));

    return $this;
}

public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
        return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
    }
    return false;
}

public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to `app/code/local/mage/adminhtml/block/sales/order/grid.php`

add this code in protected function `_prepareCollection()`

```
$table1 = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
            ->getTableName('sales_flat_order_address');
$shipping = "(select max(t.street) from `$table1` as t  where   t.parent_id = main_table.entity_id )";
        $collection->getSelect()->from('', "$shipping as shipping_city");
```

and in   protected function `_prepareColumns()`, add following code

```
$this->addColumn('shipping_city', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Address'),
            'index' => 'shipping_city',
            'filter_index' => 'shipping.city'
        ));
```

Comment: I want to display in order admin grid "bill to name" column have complete billing address and "ship to name" column have complete shipping address instead of shipping city

Comment: please help if you know answer

Comment: go to app/code/local/mage/adminhtml/block/sales/order/grid.php **

add this code in protected function _prepareCollection()
*CODE*-->>
$table1 = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource') ->getTableName('sales_flat_order_address'); $shipping = "(select max(t.street) from $table1 as t where t.parent_id = main_table.entity_id )"; $collection->getSelect()->from('', "$shipping as shipping_name"); @Kiyara this will give you perfect results

Comment: showing error Fatal error: Call to a member function getSelect() on a non-object

Comment: which version of magento are you using? @Kiyara

Comment: i am using magento 1.9

Comment: I am also using magento 1.9. And using same code to get shipping address. And it's working fine. Send me your code i'll try to make it correct. @Kiyara

Comment: see updated post

Comment: I edit your code. try this one and tell me if it is giving you required results. Thank you @Kiyara

Comment: i tried this but getting same error

Comment: Then you may have done something terrible with the magento database or with the core files, or something else. Sorry @Kiyara i'm afraid that i can't help you then.

Comment: after making some corrections its working fine. thank you so much for your help.

Comment: how can do this in magento 2