# Add Column to Admin > Sales > Orders Grid

Tags: admin, orders, grid, grid-serlization, order-grid

How can I add a column to the grid in the Admin section under Sales > Orders?

[image]

Comment: Here is an article telling how you can do that: https://www.magestyapps.com/blog/post/how-to-add-a-custom-column-to-order-grid-in-magento/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Inchoo wrote a great [article](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-extend-magento-order-grid/) on extending the order grid. And on the Atwix blog there's an [article](http://www.atwix.com/magento/customize-orders-grid/) on adding a column from a different table.

The Inchoo blog post basically extends it with a custom extension.
In case you're not familiar with writing your own extension I'd suggest you take a loot at [Alan Storms tutorial](http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world) or the one from [Magento 4U](http://magento4u.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/create-new-module-helloworld-in-magento/).

You will be rewriting the `Mage_Adminhtml_Order_Grid` block class adding a column to the `_prepareColumns` method and extending the `_prepareCollection` method with your custom field

Answer (score 8):

Its a 2 step simple process. (for ex. i want to add **Email Address and Order City** in this order grid). 
Copy this core file to you local first in same directory. app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

> Step 1 : Add following line of code in function _prepareColumns()

```
$this->addColumn('email', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Customer Email'),
        'index'     => 'email',
        'type' => 'text'
    ));
$this->addColumn('city', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Order From City'),
        'index'     => 'city',
        'type' => 'text'
    ));
```

> Step 2 : Add following line of code in function _prepareCollection()

```
$collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id' ,array('email'=> 'email', 'city'=> 'city' ));
$collection->addFieldToFilter('sales_flat_order_address.address_type', array('eq' => 'billing'));
```

The overall query will be like:

SELECT `main_table`.*, `sales_flat_order_address`.`email` AS `customer_email`, `sales_flat_order_address`.`city` FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id WHERE (sales_flat_order_address.address_type = 'billing')

Modify the code according to your need.
 Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can use my answer from a previous post on  [Add Column to a grid (observer) - Column ‘store_id’ in where clause is ambiguous issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4191/add-column-to-a-grid-observer-column-store-id-in-where-clause-is-ambiguous/4626#4626) to add extra columns to the Sales Order grid thru an observer.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrites are so yesterday ;)

You can do this using events. See a previous answer here:

[Add Company column to Customers Admin Grid with Observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72324/add-company-column-to-customers-admin-grid-with-observer/72329#72329)

which also includes a way to adjust the filters.

You simply need to adjust the grid you are targeting in the first bit of code:

```
if ($event->getBlock() instanceof
                Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid 
            ) {
```