# how to expand the view "order" in magento backend?

Tags: backend

we use Magento 1.7.0.2
i wish to expand the list "orders"(Bestellungen) in the backend.
how can i let me show the postal code from the customers there?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to go, I hope this is helpful:

Quick and easy , but 3rd party extensions

> http://www.xtento.com/magento-extensions/enhanced-order-grid.html
>   
> Excellent developer, world class support, and bonus for you based in Germany. Had great experience with other extensions by this company.
>
> http://amasty.com/extended-order-grid.html
>   Will do exactly what you want and more! (no i dont work for them, and have not personally used it, but i know it does the trick) Have had OK experiences with other modules, support more mixed

Otherwise see

> http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-extend-magento-order-grid/
>
> [Add Column to Admin > Sales > Orders Grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17403/add-column-to-admin-sales-orders-grid)
>
> [Add Column to a grid (observer) - Column ‘store_id’ in where clause is ambiguous issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4191/add-column-to-a-grid-observer-column-store-id-in-where-clause-is-ambiguous/)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot:)
this here http://www.atwix.com/magento/column-to-orders-grid/ works fine for me