# The proper way to add/remove features from admin order page?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

I'm about to migrate my current platform (osCommerce) to magento and on the current platform I have a lot of customizations on the order page where you see all the order statuses, billing address, what the customer purchased etc.

I wanna make sure that on Magento the customizations gonna be on external files so in case there is an upgrade the customizations will not be overwritten...

What is the proper way to achieve that?

Comment: Ask more specifically what you want and probably there is such solution here.

Answer (score 1):

For that there are frontend model,backend model and source models in magento to handle features/fields on admin,

> Example URL- www.atwix.com/magento/frontend-backend-source

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be by creating a custom module. This will make sure your source codes/files will remain same and not impact on update.
[This](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/) and [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17403/add-column-to-admin-sales-orders-grid) link should guide you to right direction.

You can also override core file/function to achieve even more user experience. [This](http://alanstorm.com/magento_upgrade_rewrite_override) and [this](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/) will give you an idea about overriding core file/functions.