# GrandTotal(excl. tax) and Payment Method in Admin >> Sales >> Invoice grid

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid, invoice, export

I have Magento CE 1.9.2.1 installed in my site.

Now I want to also include custom made columns "Grandtotal Excl. Tax" and "Payment method" to my Admin >> Sales >> Invoice grid and also include those columns in Grid export.

How can I do that by editing the collection query in `_prepareCollection` function of `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Invoice/Grid.php` ?

I don't know much about having subtract operation in sql, so can somebody help me out here ?

Answer (score 1):

Hello You have different possibilities to include custom column in grid:

https://www.atwix.com/magento/column-to-orders-grid/ (Via layout)

[Add Company column to Customers Admin Grid with Observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72324/add-company-column-to-customers-admin-grid-with-observer/72329#72329) (Via observer)

Comment: Yes, I am already aware of that, but as I said, I don't know anything about magento collection query subtraction operation as we do in regular mysql query, so can you help me mainly in that area ?

Comment: Yes no problem. what are your custom table columns?. Table name and table columns.

Comment: The table, grid fetches default data from is `sales_flat_invoice_item` but there aren't any custom columns created in it right now. I want to generate custom columns("grandtotal excl. tax" & "payment method") dynamically in collection query just like we generate mysql views inside query itself.

Comment: You can add custom columns of your collection follow this:
$collection->getSelect()->columns('payment_method' as customColumn','ivented_column_value' as 'custom_column'). I don't know if it is your goal.

Comment: For fetching `payment_method`, I think all I need to do is to join my Invoice grid collection query with table that contains payment method Id and it's details, but I don't know which table is it and how to join with that table.

Comment: To get `payment_method`: $collection->getSelect()->join( array('order_payment'=> sales_flat_order_payment), 'order_payment.parent_id = main_table.order_id', array('payment_method'=>'order_payment.method'));

Comment: Thanks for that, please update this in your present answer, but I guess now is the hard part, calculate `grandtotal excl. tax` in query and assign to column and fetch that column in grid and in export too.

Comment: To get `grandtotal excl. tax` is the same process of `payment_method` : $collection = $collection->getSelect()
    ->join(
        array('invoice'=> 'sales_flat_invoice'),
        'invoice.entity_id = main_table.entity_id',
        null
    )->columns('(invoice.grand_total - invoice.tax_amount) AS grand_excl_tax');

Comment: This works fine in grid and export but creates issue in filtering grid, can you explain and help ?

Comment: Can you paste the error ?

Comment: Error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'invoice.grand_excl_tax' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_invoice_grid` AS `main_table``

Comment: `@osrecio` Can we have chat over this ?

Answer (score 0):

please follow this

change `_prepareCollection()` function with this

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->join(array('invoice' => 'sales_flat_invoice'),
    'invoice.entity_id = main_table.entity_id', null)
    ->columns('(invoice.grand_total - invoice.tax_amount) AS grand_excl_tax'); 

         $this->setCollection($collection);
         return parent::_prepareCollection();

    }
<br>
and add Column in _prepareColumns() function 

<br>
$this->addColumn('grand_excl_tax', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('GrandTotal(excl. tax)'),
            'index'     => 'grand_excl_tax',
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_applyMyFilter'),
            'type'      => 'currency',
            'align'     => 'right',
            'currency'  => 'order_currency_code',
        ));
```

and add this `_applyMyFilter` function for `filter_condition_callback`

```
protected function _applyMyFilter(Varien_Data_Collection_Db $collection, Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column $column)
{

    $select = $collection->getSelect();
    $field = $column->getIndex();
    $value = $column->getFilter()->getValue();
    $select->where("invoice.grand_total - invoice.tax_amount>?", $value['from']);
    $select->where("invoice.grand_total - invoice.tax_amount<?", $value['to']);
}
```

Comment: protected function _applyMyFilter(Varien_Data_Collection_Db $collection, Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column $column)
{
 
    $select = $collection->getSelect();
    $field = $column->getIndex();
    $value = $column->getFilter()->getValue();
    $select->where("invoice.grand_total - invoice.tax_amount>?", $value['from']);
    $select->where("invoice.grand_total - invoice.tax_amount<?", $value['to']);
}