# Grid.php overriding not working

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid, newsletter, ce-1.9.2.4

I am trying to `override` below file:

`/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Newsletter/Subscriber/Grid.php` :

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
   ...
   protected function _prepareColumns()
   {

      $this->addColumn('subscriber_id', array(
         'header'    => Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('ID'),
         'index'     => 'subscriber_id'
      ));

      /* Need to add own cloumn */

   }
   ....
}
```

Here is what I am trying to do with `custom module`:
`/app/code/local/Customletter/Phone/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
        <modules>
            <Customletter_Phone>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </Customletter_Phone>
        </modules>

    <global>

       <blocks>

             <phone>
                <class>Customletter_Phone_Block</class>
             </phone>

             <adminhtml>
               <rewrite>
                     <subscriber_grid>
                         Customletter_Phone_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid
                     </subscriber_grid>
               </rewrite>
             </adminhtml>

      </blocks>


     <resources>
        <customletter_phone>
            <setup>
                <module>Customletter_Phone</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </customletter_phone>
    </resources>

    </global>  

</config>
```

`/app/code/local/Customletter/Phone/Adminhtml/Block/Newsletter/Subscriber/Grid.php`:

```
class Customletter_Phone_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid
{

   protected function _prepareColumns()
   {


     $this->addColumn('customletter_phone', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Customer Phone Number'),
        'index'     => 'customletter_phone',
        'default'   =>    '----'
    ));


        return parent::_prepareColumns();
  }
}
```

**Problem:** In `Newsletter Subscribers grid` `Customer Phone Number` not showing up.

I am using `magento 1.9.2.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite is wrong, please replace:

```
<adminhtml>
      <rewrite>
             <subscriber_grid>
                     Customletter_Phone_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid
             </subscriber_grid>
      </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```

With:

```
 <adminhtml>
      <rewrite>
           <newsletter_subscriber_grid>Customletter_Phone_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid</newsletter_subscriber_grid>
      </rewrite>
 </adminhtml>
```

Comment: It's showing blank page now.

Comment: @Hiranya see my edit

Comment: Now it's only showing `one column` `Custom Phone Number`

Comment: @Hiranya sorry I mixed my memories with the prepareCollection method

Comment: Ok..it's coming up now but in first column,how can I make it in 3rd or 4th column.

Comment: @Hiranya don't think you can by using rewrite. I suggest you use event observer instead: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72324/add-company-column-to-customers-admin-grid-with-observer

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code

```
<adminhtml>
    <rewrite >
        <subscriber_grid >
    Customletter_Phone_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid
        </subscriber_grid >
    </rewrite >
</adminhtml >
```

with

```
<adminhtml >
    <rewrite >
        <newsletter_subscriber_grid > Customletter_Phone_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid</newsletter_subscriber_grid >
    </rewrite >
</adminhtml >
```

Replace protected function _prepareColumns() function code

```
$this->addColumn('customletter_phone', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Customer Phone Number'),
    'index' => 'customletter_phone',
    'default' => '----'
));


return parent::_prepareColumns();
```

with

```
$this->addColumn('subscriber_id', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('ID'),
    'index' => 'subscriber_id'
));

$this->addColumn('email', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Email'),
    'index' => 'subscriber_email'
));

$this->addColumn('type', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Type'),
    'index' => 'type',
    'type' => 'options',
    'options' => array(
        1 => Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Guest'),
        2 => Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Customer')
    )
));

$this->addColumn('customletter_phone', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Customer Phone Number'),
    'index' => 'customletter_phone',
    'default' => '----'
));


return parent::_prepareColumns();
```