# Add Company Name to customers grid

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-grid

I need to show Company Name in customers grid. I followed exemple here: [Add Company column to Customers Admin Grid with Observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72324/add-company-column-to-customers-admin-grid-with-observer) and these are the files I created

Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ram_CustomGrid>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </Ram_CustomGrid>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <ram_customgrid>
                <class>Ram_CustomGrid_Model</class>
            </ram_customgrid>
        </models>
    </global>
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
            <observers>
                <beforeBlockToHtml>
                    <class>Ram_CustomGrid_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>beforeBlockToHtml</method>
                </beforeBlockToHtml>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
        <eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
            <observers>
                <beforeBlockToHtml>
                    <class>Ram_CustomGrid_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>beforeCollectionLoad</method>
                </beforeBlockToHtml>
            </observers>
        </eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>    
</config>
```

Observer file:

```
class Ram_CustomGrid_Model_Observer
{
    public function beforeBlockToHtml(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $grid = $observer->getBlock();

        if ($grid instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid) {
            $grid->addColumnAfter('company', array(
                'header'    => 'Company Name',
                'index'     => 'company',
            ), 'email');
        }
    }


    public function beforeCollectionLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getCollection();
        if (!isset($collection)) {
            return;
        }

        /**
         * Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection
         */
        if ($collection instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection) {
            /* @var $collection Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection */
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('company');
        }
}

}
```

While I can see Company column added to the grid, I cannot get Company Name to be displayed in table. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Company column to Customers Admin Grid with Observer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72324/add-company-column-to-customers-admin-grid-with-observer)

Comment: Jaimin, I edited the question. I followed the example in "Add Company column to Customers Admin Grid with Observer" but I cannot get it to work. Do you have any clue about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do,
As per [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/72329/2443), you only need to add only one observer in your **config.xml**

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
      <adminhtml_block_html_before>
            <observers>
                <addCompanyNameToCustomerGrid>
                    <class>Ram_CustomGrid_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>addCompanyNameToCustomerGrid</method>
                </addCompanyNameToCustomerGrid>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_block_html_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Create observer with below code.

```
<?php
class Ram_CustomGrid_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function addCompanyNameToCustomerGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $this->_grid = $event->getBlock();
        if ($this->_grid instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid) {
            $this->_collection = $this->_grid->getCollection();
            $this->_collection->joinAttribute('company', 'customer_address/company', 'default_billing', null, 'left');
            $this->_collection->addAttributeToSelect('company');
            $columnData = array(
                'header' => 'Company Name',
                'index'  => 'company',
                'type' => 'text',
            );

            $this->_grid->addColumnAfter('company', $columnData, 'email');
            $this->_grid->sortColumnsByOrder();
            // rebuild the filters
            $filter = $this->_grid->getParam($this->_grid->getVarNameFilter(), null);
            if (is_null($filter)) {
                $this->_collection->load();
            }
            $this->_collection->clear();
            if (is_string($filter)) {
                $data = $this->_grid->helper('adminhtml')->prepareFilterString($filter);
                $this->_setFilterValues($data);
            } else {
                if ($filter && is_array($filter)) {
                    $this->_setFilterValues($filter);
                }
            }
            // force a reload of the collection
            $this->_collection->load();
        }
    }

    protected function _setFilterValues($data)
    {
        foreach ($this->_grid->getColumns() as $columnId => $column) {
            if (isset($data[$columnId]) && (!empty($data[$columnId]) || strlen($data[$columnId]) > 0)
                && $column->getFilter()
            ) {
                $column->getFilter()->setValue($data[$columnId]);
                $this->_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        if ($this->_collection) {
            $field = ($column->getFilterIndex()) ? $column->getFilterIndex() : $column->getIndex();
            if ($column->getFilterConditionCallback()) {
                call_user_func($column->getFilterConditionCallback(), $this->getCollection(), $column);
            } else {
                $cond = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();
                if ($field && isset($cond)) {
                    $this->_collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $cond);
                }
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jaimin. What if I want to show Company Name in Sales Order grid? Is there a way to adapt the code?

Comment: If the answer resolved your issue, please mark it as correct, also for your another requirement, I suggest to open a new question with proper description and code