# How to extend Sales Statistics grid from Customer > Customer View

Tags: layout, adminhtml, grid, magento-1

I am trying to add a new column to the grid. Its about the sales.phtml as you can see the XML:

```
<reference name="left">
            <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tabs" name="customer_edit_tabs">
                <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view" name="customer_edit_tab_view" template="customer/tab/view.phtml">
                    <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_sales" name="sales" template="customer/tab/view/sales.phtml" before="-" />
                    <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_accordion" name="accordion" />
                </block>
                <action method="addTab"><name>customer_edit_tab_view</name><block>customer_edit_tab_view</block></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
```

This is my xml:

```
<adminhtml_customer_edit>
        <reference name="customer_edit_tab_view">
          <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_sales" name="customsales" before="-" template="mymodulename/customer/edit/tab/view/customesales.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</adminhtml_customer_edit>
```

Is there a way to manage this just from the XML?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to manage this just from the XML ?

No, for several reasons:

- the grid block with the `addColumn()` method is created dynamically by the container block, so you cannot reference it in the XML.
- besides the `addColumn()` call you also need to add the additional attribute to the collection before it is loaded. So even if you somehow create the grid block directly in the XML, it won't help.

So you have to do it with a custom module. This question references some good resources: [Add Column to Admin > Sales > Orders Grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17403/add-column-to-admin-sales-orders-grid)