# how to add customer's shipping address detail in Admin > Sales > Order grid

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, order-grid, grid

I trying to add customer's shipping address detail in Admin > Sales > Order grid
with following code

in protected function _prepareCollection()

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('Shipping'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),
'main_table.entity_id=Shipping.parent_id 
and Shipping.address_type="Shipping"',array('city','street','telephone','postcode','region'));
```

in protected function _prepareColumns()

```
    $this->addColumn('telephone', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__(' Ship to telephone'),
        'index' => 'telephone',
        'filter_index' => 'telephone',
    ));

$this->addColumn('street', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__(' Ship to street'),
        'index' => 'street',
        'filter_index' => 'street',
    ));

$this->addColumn('region', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__(' Ship to region'),
        'index' => 'region',
        'filter_index' => 'region',
    ));

$this->addColumn('city', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__(' Ship to City'),
        'index' => 'city',
        'filter_index' => 'city',
    ));
```

but showing blank columns

Answer (score 3):

The `sales_flat_order_address` address table can have 2 rows for each order so you can't directly join this table with the `sales_flat_order_grid` table, you need to join against the `sales_flat_order` table first and then join the `sales_flat_order_address` table using the `shipping_address_id` or the `billing_address_id`:

```
$select = $collection->getSelect();
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$select->join(
    array('order' => $resource->getTableName('sales/order')),
    'main_table.entity_id = order.entity_id'
);

$select->join(
    array('billing' => $resource->getTableName('sales/order_address')),
    'order.billing_address_id = billing.entity_id',
    array('billing_city' => 'city', 'billing_street' => 'street', 'billing_telephone' => 'telephone', 'billing_postcode' => 'postcode', 'billing_region' => 'region')
);

$select->joinLeft(
    array('shipping' => $resource->getTableName('sales/order_address')),
    'order.shipping_address_id = shipping.entity_id',
    array('shipping_city' => 'city', 'shipping_street' => 'street', 'shipping_telephone' => 'telephone', 'shipping_postcode' => 'postcode', 'shipping_region' => 'region')
);
```

And then add the columns as follows:

```
$this->addColumn('billing_city', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Billing City'),
    'index' => 'billing_city',
    'filter_index' => 'billing.city'
));

$this->addColumn('shipping_city', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping City'),
    'index' => 'shipping_city',
    'filter_index' => 'shipping.city'
));

// add whatever extra columns you need from those selected
```

Comment: how can i add telephone number on sales order grid?

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to join the grid table with the sales_flat_order table, this will cause higher sql loads when you have a large amount of orsers. It can also cause locking problems which can result in problems with saving new orders. Check my answer at [Add Column to a grid (observer) - Column ‘store_id’ in where clause is ambiguous issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4191/add-column-to-a-grid-observer-column-store-id-in-where-clause-is-ambiguous/4626#4626) on how to add custom fields to the grid table and adding these to the grid.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar requirement some time back, where I need to add customer email and shipping region to the sales order grid. 
For achieving the requirement I have rewritten class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` as below in my custom module.

```
class Custom_OrderGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid {

    protected function _getCollectionClass() {
        return 'sales/order_collection';
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection() {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfog' => 'sales_flat_order_grid'), 'main_table.entity_id = sfog.entity_id', array('sfog.shipping_name', 'sfog.billing_name'));

        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfo' => 'sales_flat_order'), 'sfo.entity_id=main_table.entity_id', array('sfo.customer_email', 'sfo.increment_id', 'sfo.store_id', 'sfo.created_at', 'sfo.status', 'sfo.base_grand_total', 'sfo.grand_total'));

        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoa' => 'sales_flat_order_address'), 'main_table.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id AND sfoa.address_type="shipping"', array('sfoa.region'));

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns() {

        $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type' => 'text',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.increment_id'
        ));

        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
                'index' => 'store_id',
                'type' => 'store',
                'store_view' => true,
                'display_deleted' => true,
                'filter_index' => 'sfo.store_id'
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.created_at'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
            'index' => 'billing_name',
            'filter_index' => 'sfog.billing_name'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
            'index' => 'shipping_name',
            'filter_index' => 'sfog.shipping_name'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Email'),
            'index' => 'customer_email',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.customer_email',
            'width' => '50px',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('region', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping State'),
            'index' => 'region',
            'filter_index' => 'sfoa.region',
            'width' => '50px',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
            'index' => 'base_grand_total',
            'type' => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.base_grand_total'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
            'index' => 'grand_total',
            'type' => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.grand_total'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'type' => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.status',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            $this->addColumn('action', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                'width' => '50px',
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getId',
                'actions' => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                        'url' => array('base' => '*/sales_order/view'),
                        'field' => 'order_id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'index' => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
            ));
        }
        $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareColumns();
    }

}
```

I hope this will help you. 
You can check my code and try to find what is missing in yours.