# Add subscriber status to flat order grid

Tags: php, mysql, order-grid, setup-script

I'm trying to add subscriber status to `sales_flat_order_grid`. I already got `postcode` working, but now I'm kind of stuck. This is what I've tried so far:

startSetup();

```
// Add column to grid table
$this->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $this->getTable('sales/order_grid'),
    'postcode',
    "varchar(255) not null default ''"
);
$this->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $this->getTable('sales/order_grid'),
    'subscriber_status',
    "int(4) not null default 0"
);

// Add key to table for this field,
// it will improve the speed of searching & sorting by the field
$this->getConnection()->addKey(
    $this->getTable('sales/order_grid'),
    'postcode',
    'postcode'
);
$this->getConnection()->addKey(
    $this->getTable('sales/order_grid'),
    'subscriber_status',
    'subscriber_status'
);
```

This works fine, it adds the columns to the `sales_flat_order_grid` table. Now I need to fill the newly added columns, like this:

```
// Now you need to fullfill existing rows with data from address table
$select = $this->getConnection()->select();
$select->join(
    array(
        'address' => $this->getTable('sales/order_address'),
    ),
    $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(
        'address.parent_id = order_grid.entity_id AND address.address_type = ?',
        Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING
    ),
    array('postcode' => 'postcode')
)->join(
    array('subscriber' => $this->getTable('newsletter_subscriber')),
    $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(
        'subscriber.subscriber_email = address.email AND address.address_type = ?',
        Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING
    ),
    array('subscriber_status' => 'subscriber_status')
);

$this->getConnection()->query(
    $select->crossUpdateFromSelect(
        array('order_grid' => $this->getTable('sales/order_grid'))
    )
);
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work, the column gets added, but they don't get filled. Can someone get me back on track? I got no errors, except that the transaction gets locked.

Comment: Can you be more specific on whats not working? Are you getting an error or something like that

Comment: @SanderMangel I improved it

Comment: Check http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45572/how-to-add-customers-shipping-address-detail-in-admin-sales-order-grid saying: The sales_flat_order_address address table can have 2 rows for each order so you can't directly join this table with the sales_flat_order_grid table, you need to join against the sales_flat_order table first and then join the sales_flat_order_address table using the shipping_address_id or the billing_address_id... mind the second answer stating this is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Add new column to sales_flat_order_grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5521/add-new-column-to-sales-flat-order-grid)

The sales_flat_order_grid table is updated at every order save action (sales_flat_order). To accomplish what you are trying to do, you could also hose fields to sales_flat_order_grid (i.e postcode and subscriber_status).

Then use an observer to keep your grid up to date

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(xyz);
$order->setData('subscriber_status', 1)
        .....
       ->save();
```

*Please remember to clear cache after adding the fields*

Comment: That sounds like a good fallback plan! However, isn't there a way to have them imported right away when you run the setup script? I already have an observer which adds a virtual grid column for the postcode. Am I missing a step right there?